# Display all matching values rather than the first

Tags: php, mysql, sql, vtiger, vtigercrm

I have created a query which I am using to display reports. The query gets data from a few different tables which is fine, although I cannot figure out how to echo more than one matching value within a table. For example the table vtiger_addisa has more than one newcurrentamount which I need displayed.

```
$sql = $adb->query("SELECT *
                FROM vtiger_isa, vtiger_addisa, vtiger_contactdetails
                WHERE vtiger_isa.relatedclient = vtiger_addisa.addrelatedclient
                AND vtiger_addisa.addrelatedclient = vtiger_contactdetails.contactid
                AND vtiger_isa.relatedclient = $relatedclient
                AND vtiger_isa.policynumber = $policynumber");


            //Uncomment lines below for testing sql             
             //echo $sql;
            //exit; 
            while ($sql->fetchInto($row)) {
    // Assuming DB's default fetchmode is DB_FETCHMODE_ORDERED
    echo $row['firstname'] . "\n"; 
    echo $row['lastname'] . "\n"; 
    echo $row['policynumber'] . "\n"; 
    echo $row['newcurrentamount'] . "\n"; 
    echo $row['newcurrentamount'] . "\n"; 
    echo $row['currentamount'] . "\n"; 



   exit;

}
```

Comment: your `exit` statement terminates your script after first iteration of your while loop since it appears at the end of the first iteration. Therefore, following iterations are never made and you only display the first record.

Comment: @coderodour due to the way vtiger handlers work which is what this is on it is needed at the end, removing this means that it does not stop waiting for a response, I was looking for another way around this.

Comment: If you're implying that `exit` is needed in any case, you'd just need to move it out of the `while` loop and place it before the end of the script in order to display all the records.

Comment: Yes, in that case,exit should be moved out of the loop.

Comment: @coderodour moving exit out the loop does not work, this is why I am wondering if there is another way of accessing the information.

Comment: Try to iterate through the results with this, without the exit in the loop. `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())`

Comment: @coderodour vtiger uses pear and fetch_assoc isnt used. I believe it is down to vtiger itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Multiple Row result as below.

```
global $adb;
$sql = $adb->query("SELECT * FROM vtiger_isa, vtiger_addisa, vtiger_contactdetails
    WHERE vtiger_isa.relatedclient = vtiger_addisa.addrelatedclient
    AND vtiger_addisa.addrelatedclient = vtiger_contactdetails.contactid
    AND vtiger_isa.relatedclient = $relatedclient
    AND vtiger_isa.policynumber = ?");

    $params = array($policynumber);
    $result = $adb->pquery($query, $params);
    $noOfRows = $db->num_rows($result);

    for($i=0; $i<$noOfRows; ++$i) {
        $firstname =  $db->query_result($result, $i, "firstname");
        $lastname =  $db->query_result($result, $i, "lastname");
        $policynumber =  $db->query_result($result, $i, "policynumber");
        $newcurrentamount =  $db->query_result($result, $i, "newcurrentamount");
        $currentamount =  $db->query_result($result, $i, "currentamount");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'as' operator

```
select newcurrentamount as a, newcurrentamount as b from vtiger_addisa
```

P.S- Try avoiding ' * ' and use only the necessary columns.